# Knockout js - How to pass value between two javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have two JavaScript files called **FileA.js** and **FileB.js**.
FileA.js contains the following function:

```
Reports.CompanySearch.InitGrid = function (viewModel, emptyInit) {
var columns = [
    {
        name: 'CompanyName',
        width: 150,
        hidedlg: true,
        search: false,
        formatter: function namelinkformatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {              
                return "<a href='#/CompanyDetails/" + rowObject["Id"] + "'>" + rowObject["CompanyName"] + "</a>";               
        }
    },

    { name: 'Address', width: 300, search: false },
    { name: 'City', width: 100, search: false },
    { name: 'State', width: 50, search: false },
    { name: 'Zip', width: 80, search: false, hidden: true },
    { name: 'Country', width: 120, search: false, hidden: true }
];
var grid = $("#searchGrid");
grid.jqGrid({
    jsonReader: { root: 'rows', total: 'total', page: 'page', records: 'records', cell: 'cell', id: 'Id', repeatitems: false },
    colNames: [
        'Company Name',
        'Address',
        'City',
        'State',
        'Zip',
        'Country'],
    colModel: columns,
    postData: Reports.CompanySearch.CreateSearchModel(viewModel),       
    url: '/CompanyReport/Search',
    datatype: emptyInit ? 'local' : 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: false,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    multiselect: false,
    autowidth: true,
    altRows: true,
    height: 'auto'      
});};
```

Basically the function creates on a page (Page A) a data grid which contains a list of companies loaded from a table in SQL Server.
The Company name has a link, allowing users to click it and get the company detail on a different page (Page B).
Page A is controlled by JavaScript FileA.js and Page B by JavaScript FileB.js.
I would like to pass the Company **ZipCode** to a function in FileB.js everytime the user clicks on the company name.
The solutions I ran into on the web were not helpful so far and any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Knockout, have a look at [Components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html).

The way to coordinate the two is to have a parent file that knows about both of them and mediates between them. The parent would create the data objects and pass them to both of the component objects.